# Wrap XML values with a root - sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am trying to wrap all xml values with a root value.

```
Create table #temp( ID bigint, Child_XMl xml)

Insert into #temp values (1,'<Root>A</Root>')
Insert into #temp values (1,'<Root>B</Root>')
Insert into #temp values (1,'<Root>C</Root>')
Insert into #temp values (2,'<Root>D</Root>')

Select Child_XMl  from #temp
where ID=1
for xml path(''), type,elements
```

**Expected Result :**

```
<Roots>
    <Root>A</Root>
    <Root>B</Root>
    <Root>C</Root>
<Roots>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to make sure the column is nameless; when the column is of type `XML`, it will be inlined. This requires the use of an expression, as explicitly aliasing a column to an empty name is not allowed.

```sql
SELECT Child_Xml.query('.')
FROM #temp
WHERE ID = 1
FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('Roots'), TYPE
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [ROOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/example-specifying-a-root-element-for-the-xml-generated-by-for-xml?view=sql-server-2017) in `FOR XML`

```
SELECT Child_Xml.query('Root')
FROM #temp
WHERE ID = 1
FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('Roots')
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/665e5/1)